# Solve differential equation with a least square method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, least-squares, finite-element-method

I'm trying to solve the following differential equation:
$$\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}=\frac{du}{dx}*u+u^2+x$$
$$x \in \Omega=[0,1]$$
$$BCS:u|_{x=0}=1;\frac{du}{dx}|_{x=0}=1$$
Least square method is one of methods based on minimizing the functional
$$I(u)=\int_{\Omega}(A[u]-f)^2d\Omega+\int_{\Gamma}(B[u]-g)^2d\Gamma $$
where $\Gamma$ - is the boundary of domain,$A$-differential operator in the domain, $B$ -differential operator in the boundary, f - right hand side of equation, g - right hand side of BCS.

The solution to this problem is well known and based on solving the equation:
$$\int_{\Omega}A[\delta u](A[u]-f)d\Omega+\int_{\Gamma}B[\delta u](B[u]-g)d\Gamma=0 $$
where we paste an approximation of function $u$ and variation $\delta u$ as
$$ u=\phi_0+\alpha_1x+\alpha_2x^2$$
$$ \delta u=\delta\alpha_1x + \delta\alpha_2x^2$$
and since parameters $\delta\alpha$ are arbitrary it transforms in system of equations

My question is that in the differential equation is non linear and the resulting system is nonlinear. So example
$$\int_{\Omega}A[\delta\alpha_1x + \delta\alpha_2x^2](A[\phi_0+\alpha_1x+\alpha_2x^2]-f)d\Omega+\int_{\Gamma}B[\delta\alpha_1x + \delta\alpha_2x^2](B[\phi_0+\alpha_1x+\alpha_2x^2]-g)d\Gamma=0 $$
When we expand the brackets in $f$ we get
$$u^2=(\phi_0+\alpha_1x+\alpha_2x^2)^2$$
and we get terms from f like $$2\alpha_1 \alpha_2x^3$$
Can we simplify this differential equation to get rid of $u^2$. This will lead to linear system in least square method